SELECT INTO does not raise exception when no row is found
I have an empty table stock_holdings:
select qty,total_amount from stock_holdings where account_id=1 and ticker_cd='XYZ';

 qty | total_amount
-----+--------------
(0 rows)

When I run the following PL/pgSQL code block, exception should handle the situation. However, I get following results:
NOTICE:  before v_qty: -100
NOTICE:  before v_total_amount: -1000
NOTICE:  after v_qty: <NULL>
NOTICE:  after v_total_amount: <NULL>
DO

Query returned successfully in 70 msec.

Code block looks like this:
do 
    language plpgsql
$$
declare
v_qty numeric := -100;
v_total_amount numeric := -1000;
begin
    raise notice 'before v_qty: %', v_qty;
    raise notice 'before v_total_amount: %', v_total_amount;
    SELECT qty,total_amount INTO v_qty,v_total_amount
    FROM stock_holdings
    WHERE account_id = 1 AND ticker_cd = 'XYZ';
    raise notice 'after v_qty: %', v_qty;
    raise notice 'after v_total_amount: %', v_total_amount;
exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    raise notice 'No data found error: %', sqlstate;
    when others then
    raise notice 'Other error: %', sqlstate;
end;
$$


Per plpgsql statements: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW *If STRICT is not specified in the INTO clause ...  You can check the special FOUND variable8 vs If the STRICT option is specified, ... , either NO_DATA_FOUND (no rows) or TOO_MANY_ROWS (more than one row). The other issue is you are not using INTO so the above does not apply in any case.

Why would not finding data be an exception? It's pretty standard behavior

What you are looking for is Result status: 43.5.5. Obtaining the Result Status and using the FOUND variable.

Unrelated but using exception handling for execution flow control is not very nice.

You need to use the STRICT keyword, otherwise the expression will set the variables to NULL if no rows were returned by the query.
eg.
SELECT qty,total_amount INTO STRICT v_qty, v_total_amount FROM stock_holding;

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW
Though you could also use the special FOUND variable, which is set to true if a query returns one or more rows. If you use the STRICT keyword, then a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception is raised if the query returned more than one row.
eg.
SELECT qty,total_amount INTO v_qty, v_total_amount FROM stock_holding;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    -- logic for handling if no value for v_qty and v_total_amount
END IF;


For select to raise NO_DATA_FOUND you must use the strict option. The intent is when you expect exactly ONE row to be returned.

If the STRICT option is specified, the command must return exactly one row or a run-time error will be reported, either NO_DATA_FOUND (no rows) or TOO_MANY_ROWS (more than one row)...

    SELECT qty,total_amount 
      INTO STRICT v_qty,v_total_amount
    FROM stock_holdings
    WHERE account_id = 1 
      AND ticker_cd = 'XYZ';

Demonstration.

You could add the keyword STRICT to provoke an exception, but that's typically the wrong way to go. Provoking exceptions for control flow is expensive and disruptive. The manual warns:

A block containing an EXCEPTION clause is significantly more
expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't
use EXCEPTION without need.

Use the special variable FOUND for a simpler, cheaper control flow:
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   v_qty numeric := -100;
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'before v_qty: %', v_qty;

   SELECT s.qty
   INTO   v_qty
   FROM   stock_holdings s
   WHERE  s.account_id = 1
   AND    s.ticker_cd = 'XYZ';

   RAISE NOTICE 'after v_qty: %', v_qty;

   -- do NOT raise an exception!
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'No data found (no error)';
   END IF;

   -- no reason to add an expensive EXCEPTION clause
END
$do$;

Related:

Elegant way of handling PostgreSQL exceptions?
How to return a value from a function if no value is found
Why is IS NOT NULL false when checking a row type?

